# rmysql return data type

Tags: mysql, r, date, types, rmysql

I am extracting some data from a db using R and RMySQL and the dates come back as factors.  I then have to call `as.Date()` on this column.  Because there are a lot of records, this takes a long time.  Is there a way to strong type the return values from `fetch`?  That is, just like `read.csv`, for example, allows you to specify column types to prevent R from automatically trying to recognize them, is there something like this available?  The dates in my db are typed as `Date`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bad luck. The RMySQL documentation has this to say: "*Time variables are imported/exported as character data, so you need to convert these to your favorite
date/time representation.*" So you'll always have to convert.

RODBC seems to properly support dates tough.